# C# KeyPress registered twice

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress, double-click, mouseclick-event

I have a Windows forms application with keypress event and mouse click event.

The mouse click event forwards to keypress event depending on where the user "clicked" (the app is running on touchscreen pc in tablet mode). After each "click/keypress" I block the possibility of clicking with a oneshot timer for 500 ms, so the user won't get a double click and normally it works great.

However, if the app "hangs" for a seconds (stops responding and then recovers) or is in a windowed mode and I click outside the application, if I get back to the application, then it registers every click twice. Even if I click/keypress pretty fast (that it won't exceed the lock), I get results of clicking twice.

Is it a problem with loosing focus on the application or there might be other cause to it? Does anyone know any solution to such situation?

Keypress code:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!actionLocked)
        {
                switch (page)
                {
                    case 0:
                        KeyPress_0_Page(e);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Keypress 0 code:

```
private void KeyPress_0_Page(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == key_l4)
        {
          //do something
          page = 0;
          Load_page(page);
        }
    }
```

Load page:

```
public void Load_Page(int page)
    {
            actionLocked = true;
            actionLock.Start();

        switch (page)
        {
            case 0:
                Page_0();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Timer settings:

```
        actionLock = new System.Timers.Timer();
        actionLock.Interval = 500; // 0,5s
        actionLock.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(actionLockTick);
        actionLock.Stop();
```

Timer tick:

```
private void actionLockTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        actionLocked = false;
        actionLock.Stop();
    }
```

Mouseclick:

```
private void pb1_MouseClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int maxH = 1080;
        int maxW = 1920;
        int x = e.X*maxW/pb1.Width;
        int y = e.Y*maxH/pb1.Height;
        PointF pt = new PointF(x, y);
        if(isInRect(cmlang1,pt)) //checking if click is in a rectangle on screen
        {
            SendKeys.Send("r");
            return;
        }
}
```

Comment: I think this question can only be answered if it has an [mcve]. Without it all we can do is guess.

Comment: You can easily fix the double-click problem by deriving your own class from Button and using this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, false) in its constructor.  Helps you get rid of wonky code that doesn't seem to work that well.